# Eclipse erlide can't import some modules

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I'm using eclipse erlide to write erlang code. My erlang OTP version is 19.0. However, there are some modules can't be used within erlide, such as inets, http, etc. I'm wondering how to use these modules in erlide?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a simple explanation: the inets application is structured weirdly, i.e. not like a normal OTP application. The 'src' directory does not contain the files, but some subdirectories. I really didn't notice that before and you are the first to report it. I would prefer to not add a special case, but it's going to be easier than convince the OTP team to make it right. Besides, that won't work for existing releases anyway.

Not even the OTP libraries find the sources, not with the default settings:

```
1> filename:find_src(mnesia).       
{"c:/Apps/erl9.1/lib/mnesia-4.15.1/src/mnesia",
 [{parse_transform,sys_pre_attributes}]}
2> filename:find_src(inets). 
{error,not_found}
```

The easy solution would be to consider the content of 'src' recursively, but unfortunately that would break other projects, where the subdirectories should be ignored.

It's probably going to have to be a special case. Any suggestions are welcome, and also please let me know if this is important to you, to prioritize properly.